# Excel - automatically delete the first and last dates of a customer ID

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Excel - I have a spreadsheet with the Customer ID, transaction amount and date as the headers.
I need to delete first and last date, including the transaction amount for every customer ID, how can I do it automatically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to delete all Rows or just clear values from cell but keep the row? You can try to provide the sample here.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you can use REPLACE function or a combination of RIGHT and LEN functions to remove the first and last dates in a cell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).